# Why does Chromium for Windows need API keys, while with Linux it works without?

Tags: linux, windows, chromium

my problem involves Google Chromium. Where on Windows I would download it from the Chromium Project Website and on a debian Linux distro I'd simply type "apt install chromium".

On Windows systems I use, Chromium provides a 404 when I attempt to sign in. However a fresh install of Linux, Chromium signs in without any error. This has been chalked up to API keys according to other Stack posts and Google Forums posts. What is different about Linux coded Chromium, why doesn't Windows Chromium have default keys for signing in?

Thanks for any clarity you can provide and if possible a solution to make Windows Chromium sign in properly without having to create some weird developer account through Google for the keys.

Comment: I do Chromium development on Windows, AFAIK there's no other way to do that w/o providing API keys on Windows.

Comment: Hmm well as a dev, could you explain maybe how the Linux release works? Do they actually have pre-installed keys generated during install or are they a set of "default keys" stored in an encrypted hash? What's truly different between these versions is my question.

Comment: @Tmanok, if you find my answer useful (or at least accurate), I certainly hope you'll consider accepting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came here with the same question you have, and later discovered this Python script for injecting the API keys securely under macOS:

https://github.com/ezeeyahoo/ChromiumSyncEnabler

In the readme, the author says that as an alternative to generating your own keys:

```
You can also use keys used in chromium for linux platform:-

export GOOGLE_API_KEY="AIzaSyCkfPOPZXDKNn8hhgu3JrA62wIgC93d44k"
export GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID="811574891467.apps.googleusercontent.com"
export GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET="kdloedMFGdGla2P1zacGjAQh"
```

So, according to this, the Linux version simply comes with these ready-to-use keys.

Though I have no insight as to why this isn't done for Windows and macOS, I hope it's useful information.

Comment: Thanks Bland328! Sorry I've been offline for a few days from Stack, seems to me that often times if I don't receive an answer within a day or two I can safely wait to return for some time. So the suggestion is to use bash to export known keys from its variable set installed by chrome? From there simply inset those into Chromium Project for Windoze? Seems manageable!